# Add +8 days to the current date and start Countdown

Tags: javascript

I want to add +8 days in current date, (for example 20th april) and start countdown from today (which show timer with 12 days : hours : minutes).
i have set flip clock but i am facing problem with js code.

i have a following code of javascript.

```
var clock;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
var currenttime = Math.round(n/1000);
var statictime = Math.round(1439541652.772) + 31530000;
var finalstatictime = statictime - currenttime;
$(document).ready(function() {      
     clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(finalstatictime , {      
                 clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                 countdown : true,
                 autostart : false  
             });
});
```

can anyone help me out.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setDate()`:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks simple.

```
var currenttime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var setTimeCounter = currenttime + 8 * 24 * 60 * 60;
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(setTimeCounter - currenttime, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
});
```

Have a look at js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yeqtucLs/